# Irreducible finite dimensional representation of a residually finite finitely presented infinite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Is there a residually finite finitely presented infinite groups $G$, such that there are only finitely many irreducible linear representation $\rho: G \to \text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ ***with $\rho(G)$ finite (updated)*** up to conjugacy, for any fixed integer $n>0$?

Comment: You should add "up to conjugacy", then the answer is positive.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! Yes. I mean up to conjugacy. I just added it.  Could you add an answer for the example or reference?

Comment: Yes, using superrigidity, many lattices satisfy this, for instance $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$.

Comment: @YCor  Thanks for your answer!  If I only consider the representation $\rho: G\to \text{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$ such that $\rho(G)$ is finite, is there still an example?

Comment: For every finitely generated group, there are only countably many linear representations of finite dimension up to conjugacy. (Your update is strange: since you're restricting the possible representations, obviously you have more examples.)

Comment: @YCor There are lots groups $G$ (e.g., free abelian groups) with positive dimensional character variety $Hom(G, GL(n, \mathbb{C}))// GL(n, \mathbb{C})$, so there could be uncountably many representation up to conjugacy.  I don't quite understand your last comment.

Comment: OK, just to clarify: I gave you an example, but restricting to finite image representation, then you just get more examples. So, $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}])$ is an answer to the updated question.

Comment: I suppose that YCor, in his second comment, meant "countably many linear representation of finite *image* up to conjugacy"?

Comment: @Chris Oh thanks, I didn't notice. I meant with finite image, indeed.

Comment: @YCor  I see. Thanks for the example!

Comment: If I'm correct, a finitely generated group has the property of having only countably many finite-dimensional reps with finite image, up to conjugation, iff it has no infinite virtually abelian quotient (i.e., every finite index subgroup has finite abelianization). And if so, it has finitely many for each given dimension.

Comment: Are you requiring **every** linear representation of $G$ to be finite? If so, there are such f.g. examples, I am not sure about f.p. ones.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Indeed, I expected that there are no example (finitely presented residually finite infinite group) such that every finite dimensional representation has finite image.  Also, there are only finitely many irreducible representation up to conjugacy for each dimension. But maybe I am too optimistic, since I know very little about representation and group theory.